# NSString ascii convert in NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I've a NSString in which there are stored data like this (ASCII encoded): 41303031, and I want to transform them to a normal string, so my output should be A001.
I'm asking you how to convert 41303031 to A001? There's a smart method to do that or I should generate a silly function like this

```
- (NSString*)stringAsciiToString:(NSString*)string {
NSString* output;
if([string isEqualToStrin:@"41"]) {
output = @"A";
}
return output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. For anyone is interested I post here the code:

```
- (NSString*)asciiStringToString: (NSString*)string {
    NSString *output;

    NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:string];
    unsigned asciiCode = 0;

    [scanner scanHexInt:&asciiCode];

    output = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", asciiCode];
    return output;
}
```

where `string` is my start string: 41303031. The scanner convert the hex to int then I use int to write the correct value to the output string.